# How to use localstorage in single file component vue

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.js and I need to know how to use localstorage on the login page. And after I successfully logged in to welcome page, If I change the URL from '/welcome' to '/login' manually, it is redirecting back to login page because I'm not using local storage. How to resolve this with localstorage.

Here is the code:

```
methods: {
        login() {
            if (this.input.username != '' && this.input.password != '') {

                this.$http.post('http://www.example.com/test', {
                        name: this.input.username,
                        password: this.input.password
                    })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.items = response.data;
                        if (this.items == 'You are authorised')
                            this.$router.push('/welcome')
                    })
            }
        },
        mounted() {

            this.login()

        }
```

Comment: How can you get username and password from input when the component mounted? If you want to use localStorage you need to check localStorage data to see if the user authenticated or not. You can check localStorage here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) as you would if you were not using Vue.

I would remove the call to `this.login()` in your `mounted` method, see [Vue lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) for a better understanding on `created`, `mounted` and other execution hooks within Vue.
Given this, your `login` method should probably be called when your form is submitted.

After reading the lifecycle link above, use the `created` hook to test for localStorage support.

Let's first add a flag to indicate support or not.

```
data () {
    return {
        localStorageSupport: true
    }
}
```

We assume there is support, and then do a test on `create` where we change it if there actually isn't.

```
created () {
    try {
        window.localStorage.setItem('the-test-item-name', 'hello-test');
        window.localStorage.removeItem('the-test-item-name');
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Local storage not supported')
        this.localStorageSupport = false;
    }
}
```

With this, you can fallback to another method of saving the information on the client, e.g. regular cookies.

Now, in the `created` method you already can see how to set `setItem(name, content)`, and remove `removeItem(name)` an item, to get an item, it's simply `getItem(name)`.

So, when you get your response from `$http.post`, you'll need to `setItem` to store a value indicating if the user is logged in, and you'll need to do a check for that value using `getItem` on the routes that are to be restricted.

```
.then((response) => {
    this.items = response.data;
    if (this.items == 'You are authorised') {
        // remember, you can check our flag this.localStorageSupport to use a fallback method here
        localStorage.setItem('logged-in', true)
        this.$router.push('/welcome')
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is great. Can you clarify how to getitem and restrict login page after logged in.

Comment: Are you using VueRouter? Check navigation guards, a beforeEnter is probably what you'll need to hook up to. https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html
If it's a different router, similar concept applies, maybe a different name, but they will have something that is triggered before a route.

Comment: Navigation guards link changed since that was posted, this is the new one https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html